# Dynamically generate boostrap tabs in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to dynamically generate tabs in rails to function.  The tabs will generate but the links aren't work.  The path is correct and will depend on the type of data that comes in from each clickable tab.

This works, without the bootstrap, but they aren't in tabs:

```
<% @observation_reads.each do |observation| %>
  |<%= link_to "#{observation.observation_group_id}", observation_path(observation) %>
<% end %>
```

But this doesn't work.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <% @observation_reads.each do |observation| %>
    <li><%= link_to "#{observation.observation_group_id}", observation_path(observation), :data => {:'toggle' => "tab" } %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I wonder if it's my javascript.  It's directly from the bootstrap documentation:

```
  $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')
  })
```

Any thoughts as to why the links aren't directing me.  I can see the URL being display on the bottom left of the chrome browser when I hover over a tab/link, but for some reason there is no display of content.

Answer (score 0):

The links doesn't work because of your java-script. [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) will cause the default action not to be triggered.

`e.preventDefault()`

So if you want to make link work you should remove above line.

However if you are using [BootStrap tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage) then why make this link clickable? The right way is to keep that *preventDefault* line and use `BootStrap tabs` to open different tabs. [example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-examples)